# Flutter navigation bar not change with theme

Tags: flutter, colors, navigation, themes, navbar

I try to set nav bar color change when user change theme, but it does not work. I guess it is because I use theme before it is defined? So I put systemNavigationBarColor:Theme.of(context).accentColor into home() but still no good. If I remove the code, in some device nav bar is dark others are light, didn't matter what theme I set. What's the reason please help me out.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor:Theme.of(context).accentColor, 
    ));

    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primaryColor: Colors.white,
            accentColor: Colors.grey[300],
            disabledColor: Colors.grey[400],
          ),
          darkTheme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            primaryColor: Colors.black,
            accentColor: Colors.grey[800],
            disabledColor: Colors.grey[700],
        ),
home: Home(),
         
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess it is because I use theme before it is defined

It's exactly that. Try using AnnotatedRegion

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primaryColor: Colors.white,
            accentColor: Colors.grey[300],
            disabledColor: Colors.grey[400],
          ),
          darkTheme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            primaryColor: Colors.black,
            accentColor: Colors.grey[800],
            disabledColor: Colors.grey[700],
        ),
        home: Builder( //so you can use the context down the tree for Theme.of(context)
          builder: (context) { 
            return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
              value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                statusBarColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              ),
              child: Home(),
            );
          }
        ),
         
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: weird, more feedback here: most time your code works navbar does change with theme, but some time not. Then I reboot the device, it works again. any idea?

Comment: it ended up with wrap all root widgets in all dart files with AnnotatedRegion  inside Home(). Code looks ugly but works. Must be a better way though...

Comment: Well if you push another page AnnotatedRegion won't work there unless you wrap it too, it's like SafeArea, any new page needs it or it will fall outside